# Is this method of programming recommended?

Tags: php, content-management-system, server-side

So a local counsil asked me to under go a project for them. They want every website in their area to have their websites completely revamped and they want it content managable. Long story short, the counsils budget is limited and there are not enough human resources on my side (and their are over 200 schools) I was wondering if this is recommended;

1. I will create my own PHP Content Management System and store it a main frame server. All the core files will be stored here.
2. Each school will have their own domain however the core files are stored in the main frame server and that will power each website and handle all requests and database requests.
3. Each school will also have their own database to store their own content and settings.
4. The school administrator will have access to their schools admin panel to edit content, edit color schemes and maintain the website. However the code engine will be stored on a main frame server.

That way I will not have to configure a lot and style 200+ websites. And when an software/security update is released all stores will be sharing the same core files, therefore all websites will automaticaly be updated.

I understand the server will need to be a dedicated server, which the counsil will provide and maintain.

Is this recommended, has this been done before, and their any more pros, or cons?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: To clarify, you're basically saying you would do what wordpress.com does but using a different CMS?

Comment: Well, I would develop my own. And yeah thats a good way of putting it, except it would be a unique domain per school, not schol1.domain.com, website2.domain.com,  it would be website1.com and website2.com

Comment: You can do that with WordPress lookup WordpressMU

Comment: what do you mean dagon? Thanks for your help william :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have already heard of Drupal. It is a Content Management Framework/System (whatever else people like to call it. There are pros and cons for it. One con is that it is a bit more complicated to figure out than CMS systems like wordpress. However in my opinion it is worth the trouble. And the main reason why I am recommending it for your situation is that it contains something called `Drupal Multi Site Installation` which makes it easier to have a centralized control panel to install, administrator and control multiple Drupal sites in different URLS without have to reinstall the code base again and again.

You can read more about it at http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

The time you spend to develop something on your own, you can spend on learning how to manage/administer sites using Drupal. That way in the end, not only will you be able to have achieved the same thing you set forward to achieve developing something on your own, you will also now have mastered how to use a world-class tool, which will help you in the future too.

Comment: I should add that each site must have their own admin panel (using the shared core files), which will allow them to controll their own content, however they will not be able to access all websites.

Comment: Yes. Each site will have its own database and its own configuration settings, so each site will have its own content, settings, enabled modules, and enabled themes etc.

Comment: Sounds good! I am now debating whether to use a CMS or my own? Thanks for your answer, yours has been more in depth which I appreciate so you've for my vote and answer!

Comment: Be careful what you allow the users access to. Everyone wants to have full access to everything, but in the end it turns into a cluster. Keep the options to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sort of architecture has been done before.  You may as well store everything on the main server and eliminate all of the 'satellite' servers at each location.  There are many CMS applications that you can install such as WordPress and Joomla.  It may be worth looking at one of those and simply styling it for them.  If a custom solution is preferable, it looks like you are on a good track.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me of Joomla extensions or wordpress extensions do this, for referance?

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I am not familiar with specific tools for these platforms.  However, a quick search for 'Joomla multiple sites' or 'Wordpress multiple sites' brings up many options.  Good luck.